# How to get the salary that you want if the company really needs you

Tags: salary, new-job, negotiation

I am doing now a probe time in my company for 6 month and I will get an offer from my company for full time job but the offer would be less than what I want (I know that because it is the salary that they pay for other colleagues who were new as well) and I know that they need me and they want me. So what is the best way to get the salary that I want that it is not so far from their offer?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if they truely **need** you, they'll most likely beat what they've offered before (especially if you have a reasonable expectation of knowing how much that is).

If the just **want** you, it'll likely be what you're expecting, the question will be if they decide they **don't** want you if you start pushing for more, but you need to judge this when the time comes.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to have reasons why they should pay you more. Think about this very carefully.  Whey they give you the low offer, you will have to indicate you want more and again, be prepared to say why.

You may get some type of response about this company being "locked" into what they offer new hires. What are you going to do? Decline? Take the offer, but look somewhere else?

If I were them, I would push to see why you think you should get paid more than everyone else.

Have you considered asking for other perks or benefits if they choose not to increase your salary?